# rosinstall gcc invocations?

Tags: ros, rosinstall, gcc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to have the gcc invocations that result from a rosinstall command printed to stdout. Is that possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29122/rosinstall-gcc-invocations?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not that I know of.   rosinstall doesn't call gcc directly, anyways.  it just calls through to rosmake.  Thus, you can have the same net effect by calling rosinstall with -n (no build) and then calling rosmake as you see fit.

rosinstall is moving away from any invocations of build infrastructure starting with ROS Fuerte.  The old calls were a result of bootstrapping issues.  The catkin-based stuff runs rosinstall with no build (-n option).

EDIT: to see the output from rosmake:

```
VERBOSE=1 rosmake -V
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-03-05**:
Let me clarify. I'm not really fussed about who calls gcc, but I'd like to see all gcc invocations for a ROS build logged to stdout. What's the best way to do that?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-08**:
VERBOSE=1 rosmake -V will put all console outputs to screen